# 301 redirect in nginx section Server with several domain

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have nginx config with several domains name in section SERVER. What i can do redirect 301 only for one of them? for example:

```
server { www.domain1.com www.domain2.com www.domain3.com ...... 
         ... }
```

But I need to redirect only domain2.com. to domain2eg.com

Comment: You should have different `server` blocks for every unique name.

Comment: Or at least for those names that have different requirements.